# QGIS Labeling OSM items depending on scale

Tags: labeling, qgis-2, scale, expression, rule-based

I'm working with OSM data in QGIS 2.10 (Ubuntu). I'd like to label items depending on scale. What I mean to do is to have

- only labels of "primary" roads from a scale of 1:80.000 down to 1:50:000
- all the other labels from 1:50.000 down to 1:1.000

The only expression about labeling that sounded helpful was:

```
CASE WHEN "place" in ( 'city','town' , 'village' , 'suburb' ) 
THEN 0
ELSE 1
END
```

But it doesn't exactly do what I'm looking for.

Does anybody know what I should do?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `$scale` function within your `case` statement. So you could use something like:

```
CASE
WHEN "place" in ('city','town' , 'village' , 'suburb') AND $scale <=80000 AND $scale >= 50000
THEN 1
WHEN "place" in ('city','town' , 'village' , 'suburb') AND $scale <50000
THEN 0
END
```

Comment: Ok, I got the sense of it, but it doesn't seem to be working... I'm trying to export the "primary" roads to a new vector so that I can exclude the others. Thanks for your help!